# matrix region sum function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having trouble understanding this piece of code. This function determines the sum of a selected area in a matrix. You are given matrix and coordinates of the top left(A) and bottom right(D) corner of the rectangle.

```
    def matrixRegionSum(matrix, A, D):
      if len(matrix) == 0:
        return
      totalSum = 0
      for i in range(A[0], D[0] + 1):
        for j in range (A[1], D[1] + 1):
          totalSum += matrix[i][j]
      return totalSum
```

The part I am stuck on is inside the range() function. I'm not sure how A[0], B[0], A[1], and B[1] access the matrix. Could someone explain? I see A[0] as the first value in an array, but a matrix is 2D. Could someone explain to me the logic behind this function?

Thank you for the help! much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Range is function which iterates a sequence (low,high) exclusive of
>   the 'high' element.**
>
> If you do need to iterate over a sequence of numbers, the built-in function range() comes in handy. It generates lists containing arithmetic progressions, e.g.:

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> range(5, 10)
>[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So, when you say range(A[0],D[0]+1) the lower limit is A[0] and the higher limit is D[0] in essence. So coming to the logic, its simple math.

> **Area = integral ydx.**

---

**A[0] and D[0] are the x coordinates** of the top-left and the bottom-right coordinates respectively. 
**A[1] and D[1] are  the y coordinates**. So, you are iterating the matrix from D[0]+1 to A[0] (which is dx) along the strip represented by  (D[1]+1 to A[1]) which evaluates to y.

---

So the height is calculated by summing the elements in matrix(x  ,  j) by looping j from D[1]+1 to A[1] for a particular x in range A[0] and D[0].  
And this height is added to the sum repeatedly for every x which is in range(A[0] , D[0]+1).

In effect, you are actually running through the indices in the matrix using the coordinates which are in the range specified by A[0] to D[0] for x and A[1] to D[1] for y.

> For ex: 
>  if A=(0,6) and D=(3,8), 
>  the loop evaluates to,
>
> ```
> for i in range(0,4):
>     for j in range(6,9):
>          totalSum+=matrix[i][j]
> ```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

`A` represents the coordinates of the top left. `A[0]` is the X coordinate, `A[1]` the Y coordinates ...

Therefore, `range(A[0], D[0] + 1)` loops on all X values between the left boundary and the right boundary.

Similar reasoning for the Y axis.